# Using multiple .Paginate ranges with Hugo

Tags: hugo, hugo-shortcode

I'm struggling in creating multiple ranges using hugo.

```
 {{ range (.Paginate (where site.RegularPages "Section" "research")).Pages }}
    {{ partial "research-card" .}}
  {{ end }}

  {{ range (.Paginate (where site.RegularPages "Section" "services")).Pages }}
       {{ partial "services-card" .}}
  {{ end }}
```

I want to use each of these to create cards for different sections however they are in the same html file. The issue I am having is that when I add the second range it removes the cards from the first one and if I create pages for each I get nil variable errors.

Is there a way to use more than one range on the same page in hugo to create a home page that loads different sections?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> The error message is pretty clear: It is not supported with two paginagors on one page, “/page/1” then … what do we do with the second? We may make some magic in this department in the future, but that is a big maybe. You will have to figure a way to exclude one or both of the paginators.

Says Bjørn Erik Pedersen [here](https://discourse.gohugo.io/t/need-to-render-two-paginate-sections-on-main-page/6627/2?u=jhvanderschee).

Answer (score 0):

You can not use `.Paginate` with different parameters on the same page. As per the documentation, it can be used only once per page.

> If you call .Paginator or .Paginate multiple times on the same page,
> you should ensure all the calls are identical. Once either .Paginator
> or .Paginate is called while generating a page, its result is cached,
> and any subsequent similar call will reuse the cached result. This
> means that any such calls which do not match the first one will not
> behave as written.

https://gohugo.io/templates/pagination/